# Checking to see if data is different before writing with encoding applied

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

I have a web-scraper scraping the following data:

```
TESTDATA
DATA:DATA
Data £9500
Data £930
Data £500
Data £2250
Data £930
Data £500
Data £2250

DATATEST
DATA:DATA
Data £95001
Data £9302
Data £5003
Data £22504
Data £9305
Data £5006
Data £22507
```

Running: `print full_end` Returns:

```
[u'TESTDATA', 'DATA:DATA', 'Data £9500', 'Data £930', 'Data £500', 'Data £2250', 'Data £930', 'Data £500', 'Data £2250', '\r', DATATEST', 'DATA:DATA', 'Data £95001', 'Data £9302', 'Data £5003', 'Data £22504', 'Data £9305', 'Data £5006', 'Data £22507']
```

Running: `print repr(full_end)` Returns:

```
u"TESTDATA\nDATA:DATA\nData £9500\nData £930\nData £500\nData £2250\nData £930\nData £500\nData £2250\n\r\nDATATEST\nDATA:DATA\nData £95001\nData £9302\nData £5003\nData £22504\nData £9305\nData £5006\nData £22507"
```

Running: `print repr('\r\n'.join(full_end).strip())` Returns:

```
u"TESTDATA\r\nDATA:DATA\r\nData £9500\r\nData £930\r\nData £500\r\nData £2250\r\nData £930\r\nData £500\r\nData £2250\r\n\r\r\nDATATEST\r\nDATA:DATA\r\nData £95001\r\nData £9302\r\nData £5003\r\nData £22504\r\nData £9305\r\nData £5006\r\nData £22507"
```

Image: [http://i.imgur.com/Qe0TE5Y.png](https://i.imgur.com/Qe0TE5Y.png)

Using the following script

```
with open('FULL_DATA.txt','r') as full_end_datafile:
    full_end_datafile_read = full_end_datafile.read()
    encoded_data = '\n'.join(full_end).encode("Latin-1")
    if full_end_datafile_read == encoded_data:
        encoded_data = "" 
    else:
        with open('FULL_DATA.txt','w') as full_end_datafile:
            full_end_datafile.write('\n'.join(full_end).encode("Latin-1"))
```

#### Note: Editing the file in notepad shows 1 line between each dataset/group and in notepad++ it shows 2 lines between each dataset/group

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FhV5wJx.png]

#### If I change the write and read options to `rb` and `wb` I get the following:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/hmXy6tf.png]

It doesn't recognise the data is the same and it re-saves the file

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance
- Hyflex

Comment: You use the name `full_end` twice, but I don't see any assignment. Where is it declared?

Comment: This is definitely not the entire script you're using to test this. - I get `NameError: name 'full_end' is not defined`

Comment: @WayneWerner `full_end` is defined by scraping a website, returns the text shown in the screenshots and the text block at the top, I've added two prints of `full_end` for reference :)

Comment: @micromoses See above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the file, use the U flag:

```
with open('FULL_DATA.txt','Ur')
```

This means "universal EOL", and will translate all different EOLs (such as `\r\n`) to `\n`. Difference between EOLs is one reason your comparison fails. There may be others, but start with this one.

Comment: Now that I see the contents of `full_end` I understand why - you have `\r` in there which is swallowed by the 'U'. Try `full_end = full_end.replace("\r", "")`. I think it will help, but I would use it only to debug, not as a solution. If this still doesn't help, try splitting the lines, and in a for loop print out each line which doesn't match. Once you narrow down the diffs, you can specifically handle each of them.

Comment: `full_end` is a list though, appended and formed by a bunch of scraping and for loops so I can't do .replace on it...

Comment: Right, sorry. I looked at the `repr` instead. Use `while '\r' in full_end: full_end.remove('\r')`. Again, for debugging only (unless you want to always save the file with unix-type `\n`s). Everyone here thinks this has something to do with the carriage-return, so I'd suggest eliminating it first.

Comment: wb? I don't know what that stands for.. But unix type is line-feed (LF or \n). Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to End-Of-Line conversion Python does when working with text files. Windows EOL are two characters (`CR` and `LF`) while Unix/Linux uses `LF` only. While Windows' Notepad only recognises Windows' convention only, Notepad++ recognises both. On first image, Python the current OS convention; in the second image, you're just passing binary data (and you'd get the Unix/Linux convention).

Comment: so why do the two bits of data not match when visually to the eye they do match...

Comment: @Hyflex Happens due to the `\n` character expansion in Python and many other languages, falls under the conventions used by OS.


Here's a extract of your code `print repr(full_end)`:


`\nData £2250\n \r\n DATATEST\nDATA:D`


`\r\n` holds **two** new lines instead of one

Comment: I'm not too fussed about the new lines, more so the checking I just assumed that this is what is causing the match not to exist even tho the data is indentical

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need the carriage return `'\r'` for notepad?

```
full_end_datafile.write('\r\n'.join(full_end).encode("Latin-1"))
```

You might try stripping `\r` and `\n` before doing your comparisons.  Even running .strip() on your string to remove extra whitespace can help, if you don't care about the invisible stuff.

Comment: Updated original post with outcome from that, it still doesn't work :/